# How do I make a console footer open a new tab?

Tags: visualforce, console, custom-console-components

I have a console app with footer components `Macros`, `Knowledge`, and `History`. Each of them opens a mini-window next to the respective component.

I know how to create a new console component that does likewise.

But what I want is to be able to click on the component and, instead of a popup coming up, a new console tab is opened.

Is this possible? And if so, how?

Comment: is this in classic or LEX? you can use javascript API or Workspace API to do that based on your enviorenment

Comment: @LMudiyanse LEX.

Answer (score 1):

You're essentially creating a component that "executes" a script and closes. This is very similar to creating a headless flow that runs from within the component in that your JS runs on Init to find the relevent tabs, subtabs and objects and records that are open and open the record in a new Tab. You'll need follow the documentation on using the Console API and Workspace API to ID the tabs, objects, and records to do that. There's an example in the documentation for the Lightning Console you can add to the Utility bar that will run to prevent more than 5 Components from running. It does not display. I recommend you take a look at that example to see how it works as something of a reference.